# Is every command handled differently in input redirection in a shell (linux)?

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system

For example `wc -l filename` would print out for example "3 filename",
while `wc -l < filename` would print out only "3" disregarding "filename".
This means there must have been some program that got rid of "filename" with the addition of input redirection "<". Also that means input redirection handles every command differently; such as "cat filename" would print out the entire filename to the output, and etc.

Comment: No, it means `wc` behaves differently depending on whether you give it a filename to read from or stdin.

Comment: With redirection < you take the content of the file to stdin of the program (here wc -l). To find out why it behaves that way, start wc -l without any arguments, then type some text and then hit Ctrl-D

Comment: What a strange deductive leap!

Comment: If you run `wc -l < filename` then `wc` is not informed of the name of the file, so it can't print it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is every command handled differently in input redirection in a shell (linux)?

No, the shell handles redirections identically. It's the individual program that decides how it handles its input.

`wc` and `cat` both can handle files passed as arguments. If they are not passed any arguments, they process input from `stdin`.

However, what they do with the file names vs `stdin` is entirely up to them.